# I have a issue with npm proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

I have a problem with proxy services when i need to install any package i get this error:
```
C:\Users\ihab\Desktop\myApp\myApp>npm install -g npm@latest
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: getadd
rinfo ENOTFOUND proxy_host proxy_host:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ihab\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-11-15T13_49_08_4
73Z-debug.log

C:\Users\ihab\Desktop\myApp\myApp>npm --registry http://registry.cnpmjs.org info
 underscore
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy_host proxy_host:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ihab\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-11-15T13_51_14_6
81Z-debug.log
```
any solution for this problem please

Answer (score 0):

If there is any proxy issue ask your network team what proxy url they have set . And then set proxy for npm

windows .

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@url-of-proxy 
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@url-of-proxy
```